# jPlayer swf : trouble loading media from amazon ses

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, jplayer

I have been trying to load audio files using jPlayer in IE8 with the fallback swf.  My audio files are stored in amazon S3 and I get an error when trying to create the player in javascript. I have verified that my swf is loading correctly by going to it in the browser, and my file link is correct for s3.  Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

Error:
jPlayer 2.1.0 : id='jquery_jplayer_0' : Error!

Media URL could not be loaded.

Check media URL is valid.

Code

```
$('#jquery_jplayer_0'.toString()).jPlayer({
     ready: function () {
   $(this).jPlayer('setMedia', {
            m4a: audio.fields.link,
            oga: audio.fields.link,
             mp3: audio.fields.link
            });
                    },
                    preload: 'none',
                    swfPath: '/static/js/jplayer/',
                    cssSelectorAncestor: '#jp_interface_'+i.toString(),
                    supplied: 'm4a, oga, mp3, all',
                    solution:"flash, html",
                    wmode: 'window',
                    errorAlerts:true,nativeSuport:false
                });
```